# Why the pattern image of my SVG is larger than the path made of it?

Tags: html, svg

everyone! 
I think I've got a problem here:
[image]

Following [this tutorial](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/04/26/how-to-create-svg-paths-easily-using-the-gimp/), I made a path from an image (the mirror's frame) and also applied the image as a fill pattern for the svg path. I don't understand why the pattern image end up bigger, like you see on the pic. Here are the markups:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 1949 2220"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>   
        <pattern id="mirror" height="100%" width="100%"
                 patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                 viewBox="0 0 1 1"
                 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
            <image xlink:href="mirror.jpg"
                   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
                   x="0" y="0"
                   width="1" height="1" />
        </pattern>
    </defs> 

    <path .................
```

and the page:

```
<div class="w3-container">
            <div class="w3-row">
                <div id="left_pallette" class="w3-quarter w3-border">
                </div>                
                <div id="mirror" class="w3-half">                    
                    <object id="mirror_object" type="image/svg+xml" data="mirror_frame.svg">
                        <img src="mirror_frame.svg" onerror="this.src='mirror.jpg'"/>.
                    </object>
                </div>
                <div id="right_pallette" class="w3-quarter w3-border">
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this issue. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please post a working [mcve]. Half the SVG is missing, so it's going to be hard to work out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau here is the svg [link](https://jsfiddle.net/woyp7erL/), and here is a full page: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q0g4snoy/)

Comment: @PaulLeBlau the whole project with all the resources is here https://ufile.io/1z46k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is defined differently from the tutorial. Have you tried doing it the way they suggest?

```
<pattern id="mirror" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1949" height="2220">
  <image xlink:href="mirror.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1949" height="2220" />
</pattern>
```

Comment: yep, you are right, with your code it works just nice. Thanks! )